# How to install phpBB styles on localhost?

Tags: localhost, themes, xampp, styles, phpbb

I have been trying to test phpBB in xampp within windows 7 for development purposes. After a successful install of phpBB, I tried to add styles(themes) to my phpBB install directory. I downloaded and extracted the styles to the following directory (in windows7) C:/xampp/htdocs/phpBB/styles/stylename.

I tried to set my style within the browser by going to localhost/phpbb. Once I logged in I navigated to customise>styles, but all I could see was the default theme "prosilver", but I expected to see my theme that I added in the default directory.

I'm new to this field. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your theme is compatible with your phpBB version ?

Comment: @NaeiKinDus That was my problem. I am running the latest phpBB version (3.1.3), and the themes I tried to install where incompatible. Thanks.

Comment: OK glad I could help you. I've added it as an answer for future comers, feel free to mark it as a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected themes (3.x) are not compatible with the installed phpBB version (3.1+). That's why they are not shown in the "Customize > Styles" page.